# Angular-cli: testing an angular package

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli, angular-library

I've created a new angular project like this:
`ng new newApp
cd newApp
ng g library newLibrary`

I've started up `ng test` and started writing tests inside the new library.

The main app's (`newApp`) tests run.
The tests in the library are not being run by karma.

What is the right way to run angular packages tests inside an angular-cli project?

Answer (score 1):

You can read your `package.json` configuration file, section "scripts -> test" and check the command you need to type to make tests run.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `npm-test`.

**EDIT**: Ok, I have just confirmed this. Use `ng test newLibrary` to test *newLibrary*. This is only available in *Angular CLI 6* though.

*Source*: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library#building-your-library

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work - it runs the tests of the main app, but the packages are not being tested.

Comment: Check the _edit_, it should work if you are using latest _Angular CLI_.

Comment: Thanks. I've found that. Sorry I wasn't clear enough. 
Isn't there a way to make it work by testing the whole app including the packages?  Let's say I would like to test all packages and the whole app together in one go (as if the packages were a part of my app).

Answer (score 1):

use `ng test newLibrary` if you run under angular cli 6+ like it mentioned in the [official wiki page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library)